# QuickOSM Cyrillic UTF-8 importing problem

Tags: qgis-3, openstreetmap, quickosm

When I import OSM data by query, the field `name_ru` is not human-readable, but it is okay in OSM file. Changing the encoding does not help.

Answer (score 0):

As a Russian user I had the same issue with Cyrillic characters:

[image]

For whatever reason it only happens to polygon objects. The problem lies within the assignment of windows-1251 & UTF-8 encodings. To solve it, you need to save the data from QuickOSM in a format that supports assigning encodings, with windows-1251 encoding assigned. Shapefile/MapInfo formats modify attribute names which is not what I needed, so I used CSV:
[image]

Also don't forget to set geometry export options so that the CSV is georeferenced:
[image]

After you save the data in CSV and load it back to QGIS, you need to change the assigned encoding to UTF-8 in layer properties:

[image]

Now the attributes with Cyrillic are fine:

[image]